# Здесь последовательность или одновременность действий?

Tags: синтаксис

Здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, в этом предложении - Мама спит, папа танцует - рассказывается о событиях, которые произошли одновременно или последовательно? Или, может быть, здесь обычное присоединение?

Answer (score 3):

Вне контекста сказать невозможно. Тут может идти речь о последовательных действиях:

> Мама ненавидит танцы, поэтому папа ходит на них только пока она спит. *Мама спит, папа танцует*.

О параллельных событиях:

> Я пришёл домой и увидел, что всё в порядке. *Мама спит, папа танцует*.

И даже о неких постоянных явлениях:

> Папа - танцор, а мама - ночной сторож. *Мама спит, папа танцует*.

Comment: *может идти речь о последовательных действиях* - сомнительно, что эти действия можно назвать последовательными. Можно сказать, что **начало** первого  **предшествует** второму (хотя и это не наверняка), но на последовательность самих **протяженных** действий  это нельзя переносить (см. мой ответ).

Answer (score 2):

Грамматически это обычное **бессоюзное сложносочиненное предложение**. Слово "присоединение" здесь лучше не использовать, хотя по сути оно правильно, именно такая конструкция не позволяет установить последовательность или одновременность в действий. Вообще в русском относительные временн**ы**е отношения передаются обычно лексически (словами раньше, потом, то того, после того и т.п.) или восстанавливаются по контексту. При этом никакие грамматических причин восстанавливать это отношение и нету, современная система русского глагола не передает грамматически сложных времен (или временных аспектов: перфекта, аориста, протяженности или одновременности и т. п.).

Другими словами, на ваш вопрос невозможно ответить, не уяснив, зачем это нужно. Для грамматики - невозможно (нет грамматических оснований) и не нужно совсем (нигде этот факт не будет использован для выбора грамматических форм). Остаётся только понимание, то есть семантика.

А её понять без контекста невозможно. Примеры хорошие есть у Марк Из, я повторять не буду, хотя он там тоже немного напутал с терминологией (см. мое примечание). Вся проблема - в протяженности действий и неустановленной причинной связи между ними.

Семантически эти фразы могут передавать следующее. Контекст - встреча Нового года.

1. Независимые продолжающиеся события. (настоящее продолженное).  *[сейчас] мама спит, папа танцует*. (Ответ на вопрос, чем сейчас занимаются родители - *хорошо Новый год встретили*).
2. Независимые регулярные события. *[по вечерам] Мама спит, папа танцует*. (Ответ на вопрос, чем вообще занимаются родители - каждый Новый год, например).
3. Причинно-следственная связь. *[так как] мама спит, [то] папа танцует* или наоборот.

3а. Папа увидел, что мама заснула, и начал танцевать.
3б. Мама, увидев, что папа начал танцевать, заснула.
3в. Мама спит и поэтому не может прекратить папино безобразие.
3г. Папа танцует и забыл разбудить маму.

4. Все предыдущие варианты, которые происходят каждый Новый год. *Традиция такая.*
5. Вообще никакой связи нет.
    - Вася, что делают твои родители на Новый год, когда одному из них приходится дежурить?
    - Мама спит, папа танцует.

Ясно, что тут вообще исключена всякая одновременность. Более того, даже не ясно, спит ли мама на дежурстве, или это папа расслабляется, пока мама на боевом посту.

Не уверен, что разобрал все случаи. Ни один вариант не выглядит заведомо нереальным, хотя, конечно, не все одинаково вероятны.

Вообще временн**а**я система глагола очень показательная для любого языка в плане соотношения лексических и грамматических средств передачи семантики. Русский язык относится к тем, для которых лексика имеет в этом вопросе главенствующую роль. Поэтому корректно и исчерпывающе отвечать на вопросы, подобные Вашему, весьма проблематично. Ответ ***"без контекста непонятно"*** почти всегда будет основным, если не единственно правильным.

Answer (score 1):

Если контекст *принципиально отсутствует*, то нет оснований рассматривать фантастические или метафорические версии идеи "мама спит" (мама в коме, работает в ночную смену, пожарной или сторожем; мама "слепа") - приходится естественным образом предположить, что спит она "сейчас", поэтому само по себе предложение указывает на два действия, **продолжающиеся в данный момент**. Ничего нельзя сказать о том, сколько времени уже длится одно или другое действие и которое началось раньше.

Answer (score 1):

Согласна с Alex_ander, все фантастические версии, приведенные в ответах,  не имеют отношения к грамматике, которая является наукой формальной, и не может выразить больше, чем позволяет  ее форма.

**Мама спит, папа танцует**.

Это БСП с **перечислительной интонацией**, такие предложения могут выражать одновременность или последовательность событий (причинно-следственные отношения такая грамматика не выражает).

**При отсутствии других структурных элементов** (временных наречий, например) последовательность или одновременность событий определяется с помощью **видо-временных форм глаголов**, например:

**1) Одновременные действия**

Несовершенный вид: Шумел ветер, лил дождь.

Совершенный вид: Пропал отягощенный розами куст, пропали кипарисы, окаймляющие верхнюю террасу, и гранатовое дерево, и белая статуя в зелени, да и сама зелень.

2) **Последовательные действия** (совершенный вид у первого глагола): Зазвенел телефон, отец снял трубку/стал снимать трубку.

Comment: "Это происходит в данный момент, о чем нам говорит несовершенный вид глаголов." --------Разве? Глаголы несовершенного вида обозначают длительные или **повторяющиеся действия** (Школьный помощник). Нельзя исключить, что речь идет о  повторяющихся действиях. Тогда нельзя говорить о данном моменте и об одновременности. Не так ли?

Comment: Предложение исправлено. Здесь важна речевая ситуация. (1) Что сейчас делают родители? - Мама спит, папа танцует. (2) Что обычно родители делают по вечерам? - Мама спит, папа танцует. Наречия, указывающие на вид действия, заключены в вопросе, но не повторяются в ответе. Речь в обоих случаях идет об одновременных событиях.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с Sibylla. Кратко и точно высказана мысль. Только можно было бы ещё и добавить ситуации абсолютного обобщения, которые имеют не конкретную временную привязанность действия/события(Вариант "А":когда конкретно мама спала, а папа танцевал?), а могут быть рассмотрены как имевшие место в определённых протяжённых временных рамках (Вариант "Б":в какой временной промежуток, к течение какого долгого времени, в какой период времени мама спала, а папа танцевал?). К примеру, при варианте "Б" можно было представить себе такое предложение: "Весь этот год мама чаще спала, а папа зарабатывал деньги, при помощи танцев". Но даже в таком обобщённом смысле оба эти действия считаются параллельными, даже если во время какого-нибудь конкретного сна мамы папа и не танцевал, именно потому что в данном примере имеется в виду сопоставление жизненных временных промежутков папы и мамы по их деятельности. А сопоставление не может быть линейным, оно скорее параллельно.

Comment: Ваши рассуждения (и я с ними согласен) относятся к прошедшему времени. Но вопрос был о настоящем (мама спит, папа танцует) - а в этом случае, по-моему, неуместно говорить о временных рамках, если имеем в виду повторяющиеся действия.

Comment: А разве нельзя то же самое сказать в настоящем времени? "Весь этот год мама чаще спит, а папа зарабатывает деньги, при помощи танцев". На то и "обобщённо-абстрактное высказывание, что его можно произносить во всех временных рамках. Оно становиться вневременным.